# Why do I keep getting an Arrayoutofboundsexception?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class sampleCode {

    public static void main( String[] moe ) {
        int[] larry = new int[moe.length];
        for( int i=0; i<moe.length; i++ ) {
            larry[i] = Integer.parseInt( moe[i] );
        }

        int[] curly = null;
        if( larry.length <= 10 ) {
            curly = path1( larry );
        } else 
            curly = path2( larry );

        // PRINT RESULTS
        System.out.println( curly[0]+", "+curly[1] );
    }

    public static int[] path1( int[] foo ) {
        for( int i=0; i<foo.length; i++ ) {
            for(int j=0; j<foo.length-1; j++) {
                if( foo[j] > foo[j+1] ) {
                    int bar = foo[j];
                    foo[j] = foo[j+1];
                    foo[j+1] = bar;
                }
            }
        }
        return foo;
    }

    public static int[] path2( int[] foo ) {
        int[] z = null;
        if( foo.length > 1 ) {
            int bar = foo.length / 2;
            int[] a = new int[bar];
            int[] b = new int[foo.length - bar];
            for( int x=0; x<foo.length; x++ ) {
                if( x<bar ) a[x] = foo[x];
                else b[x-bar] = foo[x];
            }
            z = path2b( path2( a ), path2( b ) );
        } else {
            z = foo;
        }
        return z;
    }

    protected static int[] path2b( int[] foo, int[] bar ) {
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int x=0;
        int[] z = new int[foo.length+bar.length];
        while( i<foo.length || j<bar.length ) {
            if( i < foo.length && j == bar.length ) {
                z[x] = foo[i++];
            } else
            if( j < bar.length && i == foo.length ) {
                z[x] = bar[j++];
            } else
            if( foo[i] < bar[j] ) {
                z[x] = bar[j++];
            } else {
                z[x] = foo[i++];
            }
            x++;
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

When running this code in Eclipse I keep getting an

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at sampleCode.sampleCode.main(sampleCode.java:18)
```

Which seems to be when I try to `System.out.println()`
I understand what this exception means but I can not figure out what in the code I need to fix to make this run properly

Comment: `System.out.println( curly[0]+", "+curly[1] );` if this is where you are getting your error, then curly is the array that is out of bounds, so you either have an array that is empty `Null` or you have an array of only 1 element and that makes `curly[1]` go out of bounds.
So what do you need to fix? whatever is going into curly or whatever is setting the size of curly

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running as expected. You're getting the ArrayOutOfBounds exception because you're not passing anything into `Main`

For example, running the program with the arguments 3 and 2, the output is "2, 3".

FYI: You can add arguments to the program to use in Eclipse using the Run Configurations option.

Answer (score 0):

@Aify beat me to the answer.  For your case

```
moe.length = 0;
```

Since that's the case, your initial for loop never executes because i=0 can't be less than zero.  Since larry.length = 0 also, you will call path1 but the loop will not be called so path1(...) will just return your input.

But, here's why I responded anyways.  The debugger is your friend.

Take a look at:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-stepping.htm

If you put a breakpoint on line 6 and run the debugger, it would give you a better view of the problem.

This should get you started on debugging your code from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that the length of curly is 0 not 2. Thus when you try to access curly[1] you are out of bounds. Your issue you are expecting curly.length > 1 and it is not. You can better address these sort of issues by using assertion to verify what you think is true is true. Example:

```
    // PRINT RESULTS
    assert curly.length > 1 :  "curly.length < 2";
    System.out.println( curly[0]+", "+curly[1] );
```

For this to work correctly you will need to pass the -ea option to the JVM. I do not use Eclipse so I am not sure how to do this in Eclipse but in Intellij you edit the run configuration and put -ea in the VM options line.

The second thing you need to start doing in validating you inputs. The reason you are getting this issues is because you initial input in String[] moe is not what you expect.

```
public static void main( String[] moe ) {
    if (moe.length < 2){
        System.out.println("Usage: java -jar moe.jar # # ... #");
        System.out.println("where # is a integer and has at least two integers separated by a space.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

You may have other issues but based on what you gave us this is what I can tell you.